# How to create an array that will store form input inside a session variable using ColdFusion?

Tags: arrays, coldfusion, session-state

I am trying to create an array in ColdFusion that is stored in a session variable. I have an HTML form that passes the input to the action page and store it in the array. but I am having issues, mainly when setting the array, I tried to use cfif to check whether the array was defined or not, but it didn't work.

Here is the HTML form:

```
<form name="input" action="html_form_action.cfm" method="post">
id <input type="text" name="id" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Here is the ColdFusion code:

```
<cfapplication name="arrays" clientmanagement="Yes"  sessionmanagement="Yes">

<cfif isDefined('form.id')>
<cfset session.urlid = form.id>


<cfset myArray = arrayNew(1)>

<cfset session.arrData[(arrayLen(session.arrData)+1)] = #session.urlid#>
</cfif>


<cfloop array=#session.arrData# index="name">
<cfoutput>
<form name="input">
item<input type="text" name="id" placeholder=#name#>

</form>
</cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

I was wondering how I could also unset the session so that it removed everything from the array, I have been reading through the ColdFusion documentation and I can't see how I can do this. I have done this in PHP it works great I felt ColdFusion would be easier but I think the lack of resources makes this difficult. I would appreciate any advice on how to get this working.
Thanks.

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish? I'm wracking my brain trying to figure out a use-case here.

Comment: I am trying to add items to an array which is stored inside a session, so every time a new item say a number or name is added it displays all the items in the array until the session is unset. I am struggling with ColdFusion :(

THanks!

Comment: After setting "myArray" you fail to use it anywhere and move on to manipulating session.arrData. so.. what's the point of myArray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like THIS is what you are trying to do.

```
<cfparam name="form.id" default="0"/>
<cfset session.urlID = form.id/>

<cfif NOT structKeyExists(session,'arrData')>
    <cfset session.arrData = arrayNew(1)/>
</cfif>

<cfset arrayAppend(session.arrData,session.urlId)/>
```

But it's still a little iffy. You are storing the id in the session as URLID then copying it to an index of arrData (in the session). If session.urlID ever has more than a primitive value in it you will end up with a circular reference I think. Still.. I think the above is what you may be trying for.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I tried it and received the error:

Variable ARRAYAPEND is undefined.

Any idea why?

THanks!

Comment: The small snippet of code above will work... if you are getting an error it's because something else is wrong. sorry.

Comment: Haha, I was scanning the code for typos for ages and never saw it either! I am now getting another error,   Object of type class coldfusion.runtime.Struct cannot be used as an array
 but you say the code works, so there must be something else wrong, I'll keep at it.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure what your first question is exactly but I'll give it my best shot!

Since you're not sure if the form.id exists or not, I'd look into the "cfparam" tag.
This defines an expected parameter of the action.cfm page.

```
<cfparam name="form.id" default="0" type="integer" />
```

Then you can check if form.id GT 0 if you so desire...?

As for setting an array in ColdFusion, you're almost there...
You created the new array which is great...
But you really don't have to define the integer for each array value...
Just use:

```
<cfset arrayAppend(session.arrayVar,variableToAppend) />
```

As for "unsetting" a session variable...
Most people just do

```
<cfset structDelete(session,'arrData') />
```

I hope I didn't miss anything...
If you need anything else - just let me know.

Comment: Hello! Many thanks for your reply, I am not sure how to use the second line of code, what line of code do I replace in the code I posted? Sorry ColdFusion confuse me sometimes! Does it replace this line:

    <cfset session.arrData[(arrayLen(session.arrData)+1)] = #session.urlid#>

Comment: Yup, it'll set the element to the next available number in the array automatically. The only caveat  is you have to make sure your array is defined first. Check out the coldfusion docs, they're quite helpful! http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec1a60c-7ffc.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6a66

Comment: Thanks I read through the docs, they are helpful, but a little too much to take in for a beginner at ColdFusion. I have tried to define the array but really struggling to get it to work, I tried using ArrayIsDefined.
Here is my code now, am I using your suggetsion correctly? I am now getting the error:

Element ARRDATA is undefined in SESSION.

My code:
 <cfset myArray = arrayNew(1)>

 <cfset ArrayAppend(session.arrData,session.urlid) />

Comment: Yep, or "form.id", whichever is actually valid...
Did you do <cfset session.urlid = form.id />?

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to store the forms in session scope?
if so them you simply need to do
cfset session.formname = form
or use structcopy function to copy the form struct into your session.

To clear it use structclear function.
to check if it exists use
cfif structkeyexists(scope, "var")

Hth

Comment: Thanks for your advice, could you provide an example of this working please as that would help understand it.

Thank you.